# Using Visual Studio 2015 Community to develop secure Android and iOS apps without 3rd party license like Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, sql, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to get into Android and iOS app development using Visual Studio 2015 Community, but I'm having some trouble figuring out a way to do it securely with the tools provided in Visual 2015 Community.

And just to clarify, I'm not asking if I can develop *native* Android or iOS apps in Visual Studio.

The apparent c# Android and iOS support in VS 2015 is a bit misleading because it requires a Xamarin license, now I know that VS 2015 Community has Android and iOS support via Cordova using HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript so I'm leaning towards using that as it appears to be my only option. I'm quite familiar with c# and SQL but have limited experience with HTML and JavaScript and nothing else beyond that, and I also understand the security concerns with JavaScript, so now I'm not really sure where to go from here.

The project I'm planning to work on is a personal project that only I will use, it's a personal password manager app that I want available on Android, iOS, Windows and also a Web App. The Android, iOS and Windows Apps will all connect and sync their data from an SQL server, so they will need to securely transmit the data and securely cache it locally. I'm not concerned about the Windows App and I'm planning to use ASP.NET for the web app, but I don't even know how to start with Android or iOS if the only tools available to me are HTML5 and JavaScript.

I've checked out a lot of forms on here regarding "Securely connecting to a SQL server with JavaScript" and the replies are always "Don't do that!!!" followed with "Use a server side process like PHP", it's the latter that I'm interested in, but I don't know where to look for tutorials or references in context of using Visual Studio as my development platform.

So my question is, is there actually any way to create an HTML/JS app with the tools provided in VS 2015 Community to securely send, receive and store sensitive data? Is it possible to lets say use a c# class to securely handle the SQL communications and local caching and just call the c# methods from JS and do this securely? Or is using a server side process like PHP my only option? If so, then my Apps would not be able to securely cache data locally, would they.

Answer (score 1):

Your app on mobile device can be safely developed with JavaScript and HTML if you don't want to buy a Xamarin license.

When they say you should not use JavaScript to connect to database, they simply mean your mobile app should not talk to the database directly. Instead, you should build a web service using PHP or ASP.NET Web API or node.js (which uses JavaScript if it surprises you) to act as a proxy between the mobile and the database. This web service can help you achieve better security control if you do follow the best practices.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I wasn't aware that a JavaScript app could talk to an ASP.NET service, I like that idea a lot because I can write ASP.NET in c# and use SQL, languages I know very well. I'm going to spend some time over the next week to investigate this, this has been very helpful!